# vuejs computed or methods: which one is best to use vuex getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

All we know that both of computed properties and getters are cached, so when we use getters inside computed properties, we have some data that is cached two times, one in the component and the other in the store.
Is it better to use getters inside of methods?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Both the store and the computed property are wrapped in observables so if one updates, the other updates.

Comment: It is almost never going to be worthwhile to worry about micro-optimizations like this. Instead, write code that is clear and sensible, even if it costs a little overhead.

Comment: Actually computed property and getter are not going to compute the same values. So no duplicate values will be stored. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your getters inside your components so they are not computed twice but instead reference the method in the getter.

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'doneTodosCount',
      'anotherGetter',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

more info can be found here:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper